# Firebase Cloud Messaging Push Notifications not working on Android Kitkat

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-4.4-kitkat

I am trying to add push notifications feature to my app using **FCM** [firebase cloud messaging]

The notification will appear on my *Motorola Moto G6 - Android 9*. However, the notifications will not appear on my *Samsung galaxy grand Max - Android 4.4.4*

Here is my code:

**MainActivity:**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("MyNotifications", "MyNotifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
```

**MyMessagingService.class:**

```
package com......

import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;
import com.innocentapps.musicplayer2.R;

public class MyMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

    }

    public void showNotification(String title, String message) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "MyNotifications")
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_tap_and_play)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentText(message);

        NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        managerCompat.notify(999, builder.build());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello the issue is resolved actually it was working but the phone was removing it as **junk** notification.